# Modular cycles?

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, cohomology, modular-forms, homology

It is well known that cocycles (differential forms) and cycles share many properties through duality (e.g., de Rham). I've been reading about modular forms recently and I came with a very naive expectation: ***It should make sense to talk about modular cycles too.*** However, when I skim the literature, I find nothing on such objects...

Let me clarify a bit more what I mean.

Let $\tau\in\mathbb{H}$ and let $f(\tau)$ be a holomorphic function in $\mathbb{H}\cup \{i\infty\}$. Then we can look for functions $f(\tau)$ that transform under a modular transformation in a certain way. Ultimately, this leads us to the well-known concept of **modular forms** of weight $k$, satisfying the following transformation law $$f\left(\tau\right)d\tau\to(c\tau+d)^{k-2}f(\tau)d\tau,$$ under $\tau\to\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}$, where $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

What I am wondering about is if there exists in a dual version of such a criterion for cycles, which would lead to a well-define notion of **modular cycles**. I expect such a criterion to exist naively due to de Rham duality.

Any guidance to some literature would be very appreciated!

**Disclaimer:** I am a physicist, so this is not my field of expertise and I may ask something totally trivial or something that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are looking for. Are there some properties you would expect a modular cycle to have?

Comment: Try looking up "modular symbols"?

Comment: @Aurel Thanks! I took a look into modular symbols. I think, they are a special case of what I have in mind. See, my question is rooted in the context of a physical problem where the 'cusps' (special points/punctures on a torus) are not rational numbers, but rather random complex numbers. Is there any generalization of modular symbols -- i.e., beyond rational cusps? Let me know if clarifications are needed.